# Recursion in javascript, function restArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Anyone can help me? i dont know where is my failure

> Implement the `restArray` function: from an array in which each
> position can be a single  number or another nested array of numbers,
> determine the sum of all numbers contained in the array.

The array will be received by parameter.
Example:

```
 const array = [3, [7, [5,6]], [9,6], 4];
 restArray(array); --> It should return 40 and you subtract the result by the number of arrays, not counting the parent.
 Example:
 40-3 = 37
```

```js
var restArray = function(array) {
  let sum = 0;

  if (array.length === 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  for (arr of array) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
      sum += arr;
    } else {
      sum += restArray(arr);
    }
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(restArray([3, [7, [5,6]], [9,6], 4]));
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor mistake in your code. As the top level array should *not* count for subtracting one from the sum, you should not have that case handled in the first `if` block.

Instead apply that minus one when coming back from recursion, so to account for that *nested* array:

```js
var restArray = function(array){
  let sum = 0;

  for (arr of array) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
      sum += arr;
    } else {
      sum += restArray(arr) - 1;
    }
  }
  return sum;
};

const array = [3, [7, [5,6]], [9,6], 4]; 
console.log(restArray(array));
```

It is possible to use `reduce` to shorten the code a bit and use a bit more *functional programming* approach:

```js
const restArray = array =>
    array.reduce((sum, arr) =>
        sum + (Array.isArray(arr) ? restArray(arr) - 1 : arr)
    , 0);

const array = [3, [7, [5,6]], [9,6], 4]; 
console.log(restArray(array));
```